# Which Ampere range and precision does my amperometer need to monitor a current of 220V between 50W and 300W

Tags: current-measurement, amperage, voltmeter

I need to measure the evolution of the electric power at the level of the electric plug of a computer in function of its CPU usage percentage.

The voltage is 220V and the wattage between 50W and 300W.

For this, I plan to plug a amperometer in series and take at least 20 measures as the CPU consumption curve increases.

I don't have access to expensive material such as oscilloscopes. I need to purchase a amperometer but cannot figure it out which model would fit, in particular

- What precision should my amperometer have
- What range should my amperometer have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ammeter (amp-meter) will not give you all the details you require for your project.

- The power calculation is simple for DC - you just multiply the voltage by the current. The problem with AC is that the voltage and current may not be in-phase so you would have to know the power-factor to make a proper calculation.

[image]

*Figure 1. Poor power-factor due to current pulses on switched-mode power supply. Read more on Wikipedia's [Power-factor, non-linear loads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor#Non-sinusoidal_components).*

- Another factor is that you will have fixed load such as the power supply fan (if there is one), any hard-drives, indicator lamps, network cards, USB power, etc.

You have two choices:

- Measure the current and voltage to the motherboard at the DC level. This will be easy to do with a multimeter.
- Use a power or watt-meter on the mains side of the power-supply. This will eliminate any power-factor errors.

[image]

*Figure 1. A watt-meter complete with Swiss socket for you.*

Answer (score 2):

**zero to 1.5A**

Power, voltage and current are related by the equation P=IV. You know V=220volts and you want to measure up to 300W.  So the corresponding current is 1.36Amps.  An ammeter which can read up to 1.5 or 2A would work well.

The precision you want from the ammeter depends on the precision you want to measure the power with.  If you want to measure to the nearest watt, you need an ammeter that can measure to the nearest I=1W/220V=4.5mA.

**Or...**

You could buy a *plug in power meter*. These special meters are designed for measuring the power consumption of electronic devices.  You plug them into the wall, and then plug the computer into the socket of the front of the meter.  they are cheap, easy to use, safe, and give all the readings you might want, including power, average power, current, power factor etc.

[image: Plug in power meter image from wikipedia]

[Image credit: wikipedia]